# Sequelize Hook before create find the last created field value and increment the new value +1

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I work with sequelize and I have table that look like this.

```
id uploadedFileID flowSectionID flowID position createdAt updatedAt
```

I want when I create new data on the table to check if there is a row, find where flowID: 1 (Example), Then take the position of last value of the field, If is new data of flowID: 1
Then increment the position to 1 but if there is a row (file) with flowID:1 take last value "1" then take the new row that I create and make the new row "position" field to 2.

My Model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const FlowSectionsUploadedFiles = sequelize.define('FlowSectionsUploadedFiles', {
    uploadedFileID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    flowSectionID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    flowID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    position: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: (instance, options) => {

      }
    }
  });
  FlowSectionsUploadedFiles.associate = function(models) {
  };
  return FlowSectionsUploadedFiles;
};
```

How I hook this?? Thanks !!

Comment: it seems like you try to reinvent an autoincrement column. You should create an autoincrement column in a db and then just describe this column in your model with autoIncrement: true

Answer (score 0):

```
 hooks: {
     beforeCreate: async (instance) => {
     const files = await FlowSectionsUploadedFiles.findAll({
       where: { flowID: instance.dataValues.flowID },
       raw: true 
      });
      if (files.length === 0) {
          instance.position = 1;
      } else {
          const position = [];
          files.map(file => {
              position.push(file.position);
          });
          let max = Math.max.apply(null, position);
          instance.position = max + 1;
      }
      }
    }
```